# Normalize two arrays with second array the base for normalizing first array

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, normalization, pareto-optimality

In order to find the quality indicators like Generational Distance, Inverted Generational Distance, Epsilon Indicator, and HyperVolume for a Pareto front I want to normalize the values of approximation front obtained on solving the algorithm based on reference front which I assume encloses the approximation front.

```
reference_front = np.array([[0.5, 2.0], [1, 1.0], [1.2, 0.833], [2.3, 0.435], [3, 0.333]])
approximation_front = np.array([[0.8, 2.5], [1.0, 2.0], [2.1, 0.952], [2.8, 0.714]])
reference_point = [max(approximation_front[:,0]),max(approximation_front[:,0])]
```

I have used the code below for normalization. However, it is for one array at a time

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
    min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
reference_front_norm = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(reference_front)
approximation_front_norm = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(approximation_front)
reference_point = [max(approximation_front[:,0]),max(approximation_front[:,0])]
```

Here, approximation front and reference front are normalized separately. Can we normalize the approximate front between 0 to 1 based on max and min values of reference front.

Comment: It would be helpful if you described the desired and actual result in more detail. With actual output and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying `fit_transform`, you can simply use `transform`. This will use the 'fit' from the `fit_transform` call. In your case

```
reference_front_norm = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(reference_front)
approximation_front_norm = min_max_scaler.transform(approximation_front)
```